# Django admin, custom template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I want to add a feature to my django administration panel where the user can upload a csv file with data. I created a custom `ModelAdmin` and a new view, which manages file uploading and inserts the data into a database. The problem appeared when I wanted to add the link to the new view in the admin site. Precisely, I need a new button in the changelist view like this:

[image: Upload Button]

I created a new template in `templates/admin/app_name/model_name` which extends an `object-tools-items` block:

```
## templates/admin/app_name/model_name/change_list.html>

{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools-items %}{{ block.super }}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:myapp_mymodel_upload' %}" class="addlink">
        {% trans 'Upload File' %}
    </a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

My custom template is loaded correctly but then the username disappears from the header. It's  like `user` variable wasn't passed to the template when a custom template is used.

[image: Name is gone]

Please help me, I just started with custom admin views and I don't know exactly how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful analysis I found that

```
'context_processors': [
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
```

was missing in template configuration in the settings file.